# Write large R dataframe to SQL Server database

Tags: r, sql-server, database, dataframe, insert

Any recommendation of R packages or ways to write large (over 10 million rows, 10 columns) of R dataframe to a SQL Server database table. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By writing the data to a CSV locally and then using a BULK INSERT 
(not readily available as a prebuilt function akin to sqlSave), 
the data can be written to the MS SQL Server very quickly.

```
toSQL = data.frame(...);
write.table(toSQL,"C:\\export\\filename.txt",quote=FALSE,sep=",",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,append=FALSE);
    sqlQuery(channel,"BULK
                INSERT Yada.dbo.yada
                FROM '\\\\<server-that-SQL-server-can-see>\\export\\filename.txt'
                WITH
                (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n'
                )");
```

Also...

Since insert INTO is limited to 1000 rows, you can dbBulkCopy from rsqlserver package.

dbBulkCopy is a DBI extension that interfaces the Microsoft SQL Server popular command-line utility named bcp to quickly bulk copying large files into table. For example:

```
url = "Server=localhost;Database=TEST_RSQLSERVER;Trusted_Connection=True;"
conn <- dbConnect('SqlServer',url=url)
## I assume the table already exist
dbBulkCopy(conn,name='T_BULKCOPY',value=df,overwrite=TRUE)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Comment: I can only use R and SQL Server in my company

Comment: I just modified my original post.  I don't have a massive dataframe to test the concepts above, but you can try these ideas.  They definitely work on smaller to mid-size datasets.  I'm not sure if they scale up or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will try the recommendation of writing to csv then dbBulkCopy to database.  I was hoping to find a way to "bulk write" R dataframe to sqlServer database table directly without going through csv.

Comment: Ah, that's a great idea.  You could save your analysis from R to a CSV file and bulk insert that into SQL Server.  I have done it countless times.  See the link below for an example of how to do this.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/